# Drawing a cube with Pygame and OpenGL in Python environment

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I got this code to draw an OpenGL cube in a pygame window with python but every time i try to compile it says this  `line 34, in Cube glVertex3f(vertices[vertex]) TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`
Anyone who knows how to correct code so that i can make the program achieve its intended function.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
##Define the vertices. usually a cube contains 8 vertices
vertices=( (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1))
##define 12 edges for the body
edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )
##define function to draw the cube
def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in vertices:
            glVertex3f(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd
##Define main function to draw a window for the openGL
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display=(600,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)


main()
```

What could i be doing wrong please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertex` is a 3-component tuple, so it cannot be used for subscriptions. `glVertex3f` expects 3 arguments. Therefore you either have to unzip the tuple or use the OpenGL instruction `glVertex3fv` instead of `glVertex3f` (see [`glVertex`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glVertex.html)):

<s>`glVertex3f(vertices[vertex])`</s>

```py
glVertex3fv(vertex)
```

or

```py
glVertex3f(*vertex)
```

Furthermore, the parentheses after `glEnd` are missing:

<s>`glEnd`</s>

```py
glEnd()
```

---

But if you want to draw a wireframe cube, you need to draw line segments for each edge of the cube:

```py
def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for index in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[index])
    glEnd()
```

[image]

Comment: Didnt notice, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Got exact output, also the `vertex in edge` my post has the wrong code for that too

Answer (score 1):

The problem is well explained in your error message. You are trying to index a list with tuples `vertices[(1, -1, -1)]` which obviously won't work.

Assuming you are trying to call `glVertex3f` on each tuple, replace the specified line with `glVertex3f(vertex)`, which will cause it to run on each tuple in your vertices list.